Any suggestions for running our own RAG using Langchain + Ollama in AWS cloud (I.e, EC2 Instance) and CORS Error?
I am building a RAG application using Langchain and Ollama.

First of all, I would like to know if it is possible to deploy ollama: llama2:7B-chat in AWS cloud using EC2 instance. Would it be possible?

Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<somedomain>.com/ask/?query=Could%20you%20explain%20marrnet?' from origin 'https://<somedomain>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
<somedomain>.com/ask/?query=Could%20you%20explain%20marrnet?


Error Details:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://\<somedomain\>.com/ask/?query=Could%20you%20explain%20marrnet?' from origin 'https://\<somedomain\>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
\<somedomain\>.com/ask/?query=Could%20you%20explain%20marrnet?:1

My point of view:

I can upload files and process other functions from React.js (Frontend) through FastAPI (Backend) but when I try to access my RAG function I am getting CORS error.

Code Snippet:
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_pdf(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
if not file.filename.endswith('.pdf'):
raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid file format. Please upload a PDF.")
try:
contents = await file.read()
with open(f"temp\_{file.filename}", "wb") as f:
f.write(contents)
chat_pdf.ingest(f"temp\_{file.filename}")
return {"message": "PDF uploaded and processed successfully"}
except Exception as e:
raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

@app.post("/ask/")
async def ask_question(query: str):
response = chat_pdf.ask(query)
return {"response": response}

Note: The upload function works but when I process the ask route it results in CORS error.
Nextjs:
const askQuestion = async () =\> {
try {
setLoading(true);
const { data } = await axios.get(`https://<somedomain>.com/ask/?query=${question}`);
setResponse(data.response);
} catch (err) {
alert('Error: ' + err.response.data.detail);
} finally {
setLoading(false);
}
};

Any suggestions? Thank you for you help :)
